# Warhammer 40K 7ed: Haemonculus Covens "It Will not Die" rule effect on units with 1 wound

Tags: warhammer-40k

In Warhammer 40K 7ed, the Dark Eldar's Haemonculus Covens "power from pain" rule gives their wracks the "it will not die" (IWND) special rule by turn 4.

My question is this: Does a unit with one wound (wracks for instance) stand to gain anything from "it will not die"?

In my reading of the rules this would be useless because "IWND" rolls occur at the end of your turn while models that are reduced to 0 wounds are automatically removed from the game as casualties.

Does this mean they never get a chance to use "IWND" to get their wound back before they die?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, IWND is absolutely useless on any model with only one wound...and thus, wracks do not benefit from it in the slightest.

The only models which will really benefit from IWND are characters and Grotesques, since they have multiple wounds each.  In practice, however, Grotesques are the primary benefactors of the ability, since it is pretty easy to Instant Death a T3 or T4 character.